# Python: reading txt file containing (alphabet and number) and updating the number

Tags: python

These are the lines in the text file

```
Sponge B - 14
Squid W - 12
Patrick S - 9
Mr K - 19
```

how do i make it so that

it becomes this:
so the highest number goes to top?

```
Mr K - 19
Sponge B - 14
Squid W - 12
Patrick S - 9
```

Also, person may do the game again, in which case his high score should be updated as well. How do i read the numbers at the end, and replace with new score?

Also if Mr K got 19, 20, 21 i want it to average every time he takes the test and around to closest whole number, how would i do that? (In this case it would be 20.)

I can read the file, append and write things to it. I just don't know how to sort the files by reading them, and sorting it out.

Comment: Can you read the entire file into memory, sort the lines in the order you want, and then write the file anew?

Comment: `text` file is not a good choice in this case , you may think about using something like `csv` or a data base for your game

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke what you mean?

Comment: @KasraAD oh, will using csv or database be less complicated then using text file? If it is i will try. By the way i haven't learnt them

Comment: @Wdoctor123, you can load all lines in memory with `open('...').readlines()`.

Comment: I can read the file, append and write things to it. I just don't know how to sort the files by reading them, and sorting it out.

Comment: Care to explain why [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021295) didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reading data

Your data *are* CSV data. Well, mostly as the score are separated by `' - '`. You could easily read back that:

```
with open('/tmp/d.txt', 'rt') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='-')
    scores = dict((key.strip(), int(value)) for (key, value) in reader)
    print(scores)
```

Producing:

```
{'Squid W': 12, 'Sponge B': 14, 'Mr K': 19, 'Patrick S': 9}
```

## Modifying data

Now, as your data are stored in a dictionary you could update any score without any difficulties. For example, if you need to add 1 point to `Mr K`:

```
scores['Mr K'] += 1
```

## Sorting them

As about sorting things by value, you can use the [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
import operator
final_data = sorted(scores.items(),
                    key=operator.itemgetter(1),
                    reverse=True)
print(final_data)
```

Leading to:

```
 [('Mr K', 20), ('Sponge B', 14), ('Squid W', 12), ('Patrick S', 9)]
```

## Writing back

You have to output each record using the right format `<name> - <score>`. 
Here, I use [`"{} - {}".format(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) for that exact purpose:

```
with open('/tmp/out.txt', 'wt') as outfile:
    for key,value in final_data:
        outfile.write("{} - {}\n".format(key,value))
```

Comment: and edit the number and average them? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Wdoctor123 I already explain how to sort in the answer. As about "averaging the numbers", that part in not really clear to me. But I think you now have more than enough informations to get back to work ;)

Comment: what does     "{} - {}\n" mean? Oh, sorry let me make it little clearer. Lets say Mr K does the game for the 2nd or 3rd time, i want his 1st, 2nd and 2rd scores to be averaged. so when he does 2nd time, 1st and 2nd score averages and updates the score.

Comment: so if i wanted to do averaging, should i do scores['Mr K'] = (scores+newscore)/2  ?